# Jmeter variable assertion

Tags: jmeter

I want to load string into variables from a local .log file (which works) and then check for a particular string.

I tried Response Assertion but this is only for HTTP responses?

Comment: Ross, welcome to SO. We can help you better if you include more details in your question. Can you show how you're loading variables from file? What other string are you checking for?

Answer (score 7):

The choices of JMeter Assertion scope are in:

- Main sample and sub-samples
- Main sample only
- Sub-samples only
- **JMeter Variable**

You can use [Dummy Sampler](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/DummySampler/) as a parent for you assertion, assertion should be configured as per below image:

[image: JMeter Variable Assertion]

See [How to Use JMeter Assertions in 3 Easy Steps](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps) guide for more information on using assertions.

Comment: For me, in jMeter 2.13, I had to use the plain variable name without the ${}. So in the screenshot above the variable would just be **myVariable**. Otherwise I got `Assertion failure message: Response was null`.

Comment: I got the same results as @Joshua says. The correct way is to use ${} notation at Patterns to Test, use NO ${} at Jmeter Variable, only variable names.

Comment: Dummy sampler is not a must.

Answer (score 1):

On the Response Assertion, one of the selections should enable you to assert on a variable.

Look for the check box "JMeter Variable" and enter the variable name in the text box next to the option.  This will cause the response assertion to look at the value of the variable, not sampler data.

Hope that helps, if not please clarify the question!